# Is it possible to measure network traffic when executing Azure Data Factory Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, traffic

When executing "Azure Data Factory Pipeline".

Is there a way to monitor internal and external traffic transmission status?

In the metric or warning of 'Datafactory',

I couldn't see the corresponding part of the measurable term item,

so I asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Self-Hosted Integration Runtime in the ADF pipelines then you can monitor the network traffic on the IR VM whenever you execute the pipeline